# Regular expression look ahead

Tags: c#, regex

I've looked through the forums for something similar, but couldn't quite find what I need.

I'm reading in strings like this:

```
11/2/2017  12:26:42.064  OUT         <stx>1H|\^&|||3_7556_Batman|||||cobas 8000|TSDWN|P|1<cr>P|1||221074||DOE^JOHN||19990622|M<cr>O|1|221074|0^50010^3^^S1^|^^^962^\^^^993^\^^^994^\^^^8228^|S|20171102084806|20171102084000||||A||||1||||||||||O<cr>C|1|L|DOE,JOHN^221074^^^|G<cr>L|1|N<cr><etx>C0<cr><lf>
```

and spliting them using the regular expression `@"\s{2,}"`
My problem is that sometimes the string contains multiple spaces after the `<stx>` line. Example:

```
11/2/2017  12:26:42.064  OUT         <stx>1H|\^&|||3_7556_Batman|||||cobas 8000|TSDWN|P|1<cr>P|1||221074||DOE^JOHN||19990622|M<cr>O|1|221074|0^50010^3^^S1^|^^^962^\^^^993^\^^^994^\^^^8228^|S|20171102084806|        |||A||||1||||||||||O<cr>C|1|L|DOE,JOHN^221074^^^|G<cr>L|1|N<cr><etx>C0<cr><lf>
```

I only want to capture multiple spaces that occur before `<stx>`. I've tried some positive lookaheads, but its capturing too many groups. `@"\s{2,}(?=(.*)(<stx>))"`

I only need the 4 sets of information: Date, Time, Out, Message

Comment: Well, remove the extra parentheses, [`\s{2,}(?=.*<stx>)`](https://regex101.com/r/PsbeVm/1)

Comment: Well, doing so split my string into too many components. I should Add that I only need the 4 sets of information

Comment: Why not split on runs of `\s{2,}`? With the example, that produces 4 fields.

Comment: Perhaps having the capturing groups is the only way. I wanted a data set of 4, this creates a a data set of 8, the matching segment + stx. I can make this work.

Comment: @dawg, I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Show your code. https://regex101.com/r/PsbeVm/1 works for you.

Comment: The line in question is just:

var split = Regex.Split(line, @"\s{2,}(?=.*(<stx>))");

Comment: Use `@"\s{2,}(?=.*<stx>)"` - see https://ideone.com/erfnKr

Comment: @user3434042: Well IF the `<cr>` and `<lf>` are those text literals, you only need to split the string on runs of spaces greater than 2. [See example](https://regex101.com/r/jw33Ii/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C# [`Regex.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy(v=vs.110).aspx), captured substrings are returned together with the split chunks.

You need to remove the capturing groups from the pattern:

```
var line = @"11/2/2017  12:26:42.064  OUT         <stx>1H|\^&|||3_7556_Batman|||||cobas 8000|TSDWN|P|1<cr>P|1||221074||DOE^JOHN||19990622|M<cr>O|1|221074|0^50010^3^^S1^|^^^962^\^^^993^\^^^994^\^^^8228^|S|20171102084806|20171102084000||||A||||1||||||||||O<cr>C|1|L|DOE,JOHN^221074^^^|G<cr>L|1|N<cr><etx>C0<cr><lf>";
var split = Regex.Split(line, @"\s{2,}(?=.*<stx>)");
foreach (var s in split)
{
   Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/erfnKr)

Output:

```
11/2/2017
12:26:42.064
OUT
<stx>1H|\^&|||3_7556_Batman|||||cobas 8000|TSDWN|P|1<cr>P|1||221074||DOE^JOHN||19990622|M<cr>O|1|221074|0^50010^3^^S1^|^^^962^\^^^993^\^^^994^\^^^8228^|S|20171102084806|20171102084000||||A||||1||||||||||O<cr>C|1|L|DOE,JOHN^221074^^^|G<cr>L|1|N<cr><etx>C0<cr><lf>
```

Comment: @Ωmega The current problem OP has is more related to the use of capturing groups in the pattern rather than the pattern itself. BTW, `(?=.*\s{2}<stx>)\s{2,}` will only match 2 or more whitespace chunks if there is `<stx>` preceded with 2 whitespaces, while OP states they *only want to capture multiple spaces that occur before `<stx>`*. So, what you suggest is not really going to work for OP.

Comment: I believe you misunderstood OP and the spaces immediately before `<stx>` are required. Your code will match even strings that comes with no such spaces immediately before it: https://ideone.com/F1HVZG

Answer (score 0):

It should be sufficient to use a lookahead like so

```
\s{2,}(?=<stx>)
```

Get all occurrences of at least two spaces followed by `<stx>`